# Cannot install Kurento Media Server on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: server, 16.10

Im trying to install Kurento Media Server 6 on ubuntu 16.10 and in the final step of the installation docs im getting an erorr like...

```
$ sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libboost-filesystem1.58.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-log1.58.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-program-options1.58.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-system1.58.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-thread1.58.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-bad (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix this??

Comment: Please run this `sudo apt install -f` to fix them. Then `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and finally try installing again. Note each should work before moving to the next command

Comment: @George Im still getting the error message

Comment: at what stage of the commands are you getting error messages?

Comment: @George after executing the command sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0

Comment: In other words the other commands work?

Comment: @George yes all the commands executes without issues except the kurento-media-sever installation command. i followed all the steps you mentioned and im still getting the same error message as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need change source to Ubuntu 16 install 14by default: **trusty -> xenial**

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org **xenial** kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

Hope this will help you!

Bgs,

Comment: will this work for yakkety ?